# How can I add an exception to the mod_rewrite which redirects all traffic on a webserver to https?

Tags: https, apache

I'm currently using the below script which I found online:

```
    #########################################
    #### BEGIN EDIT FOR MOD_REWRITE ####
    #### This is intended to force HTTPS ####
    #### for all inbound HTTP requests ####

    ####
    # This module (mod_rewrite) simply tells Apache2 that all connections to
    # port 80 need to go to port 443 . SSL . No exceptions
    ####

    
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    
    
    RewriteEngine on

    ####
    # The line below sets the rewrite condition for mod_rewrite.so.
    # That is, if the server port does not equal 443, then this condition is true
    ####

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$

    ####
    # The line below is the rule, it states that if above condition is true,
    # and the request can be any url, then redirect everything to https:// plus
    # the original url that was requested.
    ####

    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
    

    #### END EDIT FOR MOD_REWRITE ####
    #######################################
```

The script is added to my httpd.conf file which runs on an CentOS server in a LAMP stack. It does exactly what I need it to, which is to redirect all traffic to any of the sites on the server to https.

However, I would like to make an exception for one of the sites hosted on the server which does not need to use https. How can I go about configuring this exception?

My apologies for what may an elementary question as I'm not a developer by trade.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to add the line below as a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www\.example\.com*
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I don't see how this adds an exception for a single site on the server...can you please explain?

Comment: Add this to site which you want to have redirect to https